# Spring Boot with Spring Security - Two Factor Authentication with SMS/ PIN/ TOTP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, two-factor-authentication

I'm working on a Spring Boot 2.5.0 web application with Spring Security form login using Thymeleaf. I'm looking for ideas on how to implement two factor authentication (2FA) with spring security form login.

The requirement is that when a user logs in with his username and password via. the login form, if the username and password authentication is successful an SMS code should be sent to the registered mobile number of the user and he should be challenged with another page to enter the SMS code. If user gets the SMS code correctly, he should be forwarded to the secured application page.

On the login form, along with the username and password, the user is also requested to enter the text from a captcha image which is verified using a `SimpleAuthenticationFilter` which extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

This is the current `SecurityConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)    
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/images/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/login/**",
                        "/captcha/**",
                        "/public/**",
                        "/user/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .and().logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSONID")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .permitAll()
            .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .and().sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(5)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                .expiredUrl("/login?error=5");
    }

    public SimpleAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        SimpleAuthenticationFilter filter = new SimpleAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    /** TO-GET-SESSIONS-STORED-ON-SERVER */
    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

}
```

And this is the `SimpleAuthenticationFilter` mentioned above.

```
public class SimpleAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_CAPTCHA_KEY = "captcha";
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        
        String captchaFromSession = null;
        if (session.getAttribute("captcha") != null) {
            captchaFromSession = session.getAttribute("captcha").toString();
        } else {
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException("INVALID SESSION");
        }
        
        String captchaFromRequest = obtainCaptcha(request);
        if (captchaFromRequest == null) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("INVALID CAPTCHA");
        }
        
        if (!captchaFromRequest.equals(captchaFromSession)) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("INVALID CAPTCHA");
        }
        
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = getAuthRequest(request);
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        
        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }
        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    }
    
    private String obtainCaptcha(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_CAPTCHA_KEY);
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how to approach this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Security has an [mfa sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/mfa) to get you started. It uses Google Authenticator with an OTP, but you can plug in sending/verifying your SMS short-code instead.

You might also consider keeping the captcha verification separate from the (out of the box) authentication filter. If they are separate filters in the same filter chain, it will have the same effect with less code.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working correctly. After third factor authentication it redirects back to login.

Comment: @Krishnaraj, it works. But you may not have noticed that the username is `user@example.com`. If you use `user` or any other invalid username, you get a honeypot flow with an anonymous user, which will always fail to validate, redirecting you back to the login page at the end. You can change that by changing the `.failureHandler()`.